# Catchment area calculation

Tags: qgis, buffer, catchment-area

I am trying to shortlist optimal physical locations in my county for developing recycling centres that serve the population.

I have a vector point layer of the centre point of around 100 potential sites and a polygon layer of urban/built-up area. I've a known catchment of 2km as a reasonable distance for a recycling centre and I'm wishing to choose a number of my 100 sites to provide complete coverage over my urban area for recycling activities.

Is there a way using QGIS of calculating/selecting the most rational sites to be chosen for developing as a recycling centre based on their intended catchment?

Some overlap is OK, and I realise that the reality on the ground may be very different to arbitrarily choosing sites based on the distance between them e.g. topography, natural barriers, roads etc. However, I just want a simple model for now that will at least show me roughly where may be sensible to develop the recycling centres.

Alternatively if I was looking at the problem as a blank slate e.g. no potential sites identified, is there a way of suggesting optimal locations for *n* recycling sites that provide complete coverage for my urban population given that each site will have a catchment of around 2km?

As you can see from the attached image the sites are by no means evenly distributed.

[image: Sample point and polygon layers]